# Substituting red beans for adzuki beans?

Tags: substitutions, japanese-cuisine

I've recently gotten into making mochi and really wanted to try my hand at daifuku (red bean paste-filled mochi) and I'm finding that there is an upsetting lack of adzuki/azuki beans available in my area.

I've seen suggestions for using dark red kidney beans as a substitute, but I want to know if I could  possibly use the small red beans I have in my pantry already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Substitute for red bean paste?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15943/substitute-for-red-bean-paste)

Comment: Well personally I would not substitute red beans and definitely not kidney beans. But why not buy them online? You should be able to find whole beans or bean paste easily. Google search or checking websites of Japanese grocers in your area should turn up many options. I can't imagine that whole beans or canned paste would have any shipping issues.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, because the other question asked for any possible substitute, and never addressed this particular possibility. But the link's helpful!

Comment: I don't recommend red kidney beans, but I've proposed some other alternatives here http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27495/azuki-bean-substitute-for-anpan

Comment: Is there a Chinatown nearby ? Red beans or red bean paste will surely be sold in any Chinatown...

Answer (score 4):

My experience is that adzuki have a very different taste and texture than red beans and I wouldn't substitute one for the other.  If you've really gotten into mochi, it will be worth the effort to find adzuki  - I've bought them in natural food stores, Whole Foods and on line  And I buy in bulk so I never run out.  Beans seem to last forever.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use them, and you can also use black beans. It won't be exactly the same but as long as you make it properly it will work.